# Why to update statistics every 30 Min.?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, statistics

In our SQL Server 2012 database, there are 3 big tables that require statistic updates every 30 minutes. Otherwise, the optimizer picks the wrong path to read.

This leads to timeouts, even if they are hit very frequently. The ratio in terms of size is always the same. Any idea of how avoid this?

Comment: You might want to consider query hints, rather than relying on statistics.

Comment: When you say the optimizer chooses the wrong path, what do you mean?  Is It doing an index seek rather than a scan or vice versa?  Is it choosing an incorrect join type?  Is the whole plan shape off?  

How frequently is the table updated, and in what types of ways?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your notes. Looks I have to do some more homework! :) So, will check several things and get back! BR!!